# how to select sum of column based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

I have the following table in a database. I want to be able to get the sum of the value colum but only based on the date. so if today was january 1st i only want the sum for every value that has jan 1st as the date. I am using the following:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value_today FROM table_value GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC
```

Only problem is that it only returns the sum for december 22 and nothing new entered into the database.

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| ID    | value   | date       |
+-------+---------+------------+
|   1   |   3     | 2011-12-22 |
|   2   |   2     | 2011-12-22 |
|   3   |   4     | 2011-12-22 |
|   4   |   2     | 2012-01-01 |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value_today FROM table_value WHERE date = CURDATE()
```

Something like this?

If it is not, maybe you can rephrase your question.

Comment: I suppose you are using this in a php script or something? You should first check if there is a result. See through your db wrapper documentation to get the number of rows from a recordset.

Comment: You need neither the `GROUP BY` nor the `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value_today FROM table_value WHERE date = DATE(NOW())
```

In that way, you could retrive only today data sum.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(value), date FROM table WHERE date = 2012-01-01 ORDER BY date DESC
```